# MariaDB - Create Foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to  create a Foreign key in MariaDB:

```
ALTER TABLE `t_time_lapse` ADD CONSTRAINT `time_lapse_company_uk` FOREIGN KEY(`COMPANY_ID`) REFERENCES `T_COMPANY`(`ID`);
```

but I have this error:

```
Can't create table `lopes_db`.`t_time_lapse` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be multiple reasons for the error. The data type of your foreign key column (COMPANY_ID) and reference column (ID) may not be same. Or there can be standardization issues as well. I would suggest you to check the issue and resolve it. If you still wanted to force create the foreign key, please use below statements,

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=OFF;
ALTER TABLE `t_time_lapse` ADD CONSTRAINT `time_lapse_company_uk` FOREIGN KEY(`COMPANY_ID`) REFERENCES `T_COMPANY`(`ID`);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=ON;
```